# lastlogin property not listed when using DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName);

Tags: c#, authentication

I'm trying to get the latest login date of the machine an app is running on.  According to all the examples I've seen you should use the `DirectoryEntry` object with `WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName` and then loop through the list of the results children

```
foreach (DirectoryEntry de in dirs.Children)
```

and look for the `lastlogin` property for this value.

But when doing this, there is no `lastlogin` property in the children. I have written all the properties names out via `Console.WriteLine`, but that property is nowhere to be seen. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What documentation are you referencing that indicates that is a valid property of `DirectoryEntry` class? It's not listed as a propety on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, looks like you're not going deep enough. Check out the answer on the following post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00563f05-ad0e-481d-93db-df1d72c593fc/fetch-last-logon-details-from-active-directory-using-cnet?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Jacob - Saw that link earlier https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00563f05-ad0e-481d-93db-df1d72c593fc/fetch-last-logon-details-from-active-directory-using-cnet?forum=csharpgeneral but it is dealing with domain controllers using LDAP.  I'm trying to use WinNT on the machine the app is running on.